# Имя переменной как её значение или удобная функция по принятию post\get

Tags: php

Доброй ночи гуру, подскажите азы, как имя самой переменной использовать как значение, скажем $fx = "абв"; $a = $fx; и $a должно быть "fx", ну или "$fx", а не "абв".
Пример из жизни:

```
mydata.php?fx=123

function getdata (&$newvar){
if (!empty($_GET["имя переменной"])) $newvar = $_GET["имя переменной"];
else $newvar = 0;
}

getdata($fx);
print $fx;
```

Суть функции назначить переменную, если она есть в гет то значение ииз гет, если нет в гет то 0.

"имя переменной" должно быть "fx" для данного примера.
Пробовал и $$ и & и {} и чтото не заработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) вам в помощь. Например:

```
// mydata.php?music=peacedata

$field = 'music';
$iMusic = filter_input( INPUT_GET, $field, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
echo $iMusic; // peacedata
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
if( isset( $_GET['fx'] ) ) eval( "\$fx = \$_GET['fx'];" );
else eval( "\$fx = 0;" );
```

Или:

```
$var = 'fx';
if( isset( $_GET[$var] ) ) eval( "\$$var = \$_GET[$var];" );
else eval( "\$$var = 0;" );
```

Но вообще, обычно если возникают подобные мысли (привет, `register_globals`!), то их надо кувалдой загонять обратно, а не развивать.

Comment: Да нет, не регистр_глобалс, я же знаю откуда беру переменную и её имя. Скажем удобно сделать функции, типа getdata($myvar), postdata($myvar) и вних вклеить все isset, trim, escape_html_char, escape_sql_char и тд чем миллион раз в каждом документе и писать по паре строчек на переменную.

Comment: `$fx = get_data('fx')` - самый удобный способ.

Comment: это глупо когда имя переменной в скрипте совпадает с именем из GET\POST? Я тут ещё подумал про foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) { } как вам такой способ? Но как бы первого моего вопроса это не отменяет...

Comment: а чего глупого ? одна сущность - одно имя.

Comment: Это не глупо. Только представьте, что завтра вам пришлось изменить имя GET-параметра с 'fx' на 'zx'. Будете весь код перелопачивать для замены $fx на $zx? IDE с рефакторингом, конечно, рулят. Но что будете делать, если имя в GET будет начинаться с цифры, например?

В любом случае выше пример `get_data()`, работает как вам хочется.